# Como baixar uma tabela do quasar em formato de excel (xlsx)?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-excel, vue.js, exportação, quasar

O quasar só apresenta exemplos de como baixar uma tabela no formato CSV. Gostaria de saber se é possível, usando a mesma lógica, baixar tabelas no excel.
Código de como eu estou fazendo. O arquivo chega a ser baixado, mas, não abre. O excel diz que o arquivo está ou com extensão errada ou corrompido.

```
    function wrapExcelValue (val, formatFn) {
  let formatted = typeof formatFn !== 'undefined'
    ? formatFn(val)
    : val

  formatted = typeof formatted === 'undefined' || formatted === null
    ? ''
    : String(formatted)

  formatted = formatted.split('"').join('""').split('\n').join('\\n').split('\r').join('\\r')
  return `"${formatted}"`
}

exportExcel () {
      // naive encoding to excel format
      console.log('Excel')
      const content = [this.columns.map(col => wrapExcelValue(col.label))].concat(
        this.data.map(row => this.columns.map(col => wrapExcelValue(
          row[col.name],
          col.format
        )).join(','))
      ).join('\r\n')

      const date = new Date()

      const status = exportFile(
        'mensagens_' + this.altDate(date.getTime()) + '.xlsx',
        content,
        'text/xlsx'
      )

      if (status !== true) {
        this.$q.notify({
          message: 'Download rejeitado pelo navegador...',
          color: 'negative',
          icon: 'warning'
        })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente, um arquivo Xlsx não é tão simples como um CSV, então irá precisar da ajudad e uma outra lib, como por exemplo à [SheetJS js-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

Aqui um exemplo de utilização.

```js
var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet([
  { A:"S", B:"h", C:"e", D:"e", E:"t", F:"J", G:"S" },
  { A: 1,  B: 2,  C: 3,  D: 4,  E: 5,  F: 6,  G: 7  },
  { A: 2,  B: 3,  C: 4,  D: 5,  E: 6,  F: 7,  G: 8  }
], {header:["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"], skipHeader:true});
```